# check $this->db->get() is empty or not

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using `codeigniter` framework.

how can I do check `get` function is empty or not?

```
...
$result = $this->db->get() 
 //how to check $result is empty or not ?
```

Comment: you can use `if($result->num_rows())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
  //record exists - hence fetch the row              
  $result = $query->row();               
} 
else
{
  //Record do not exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Better way according to [Codeigniter Active records Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)**

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {                   
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            echo $row->title;
        }               
    }
    else{
        //no record found.
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like below,

```
$result = $this->db->get() ;

if($result->num_rows() != 0){
  //you can do anything with data here
}
else{
  //empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Now check $result value its empty or not.

```
if(!empty($result)){
//code if not empty
}
else{
//code if empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $this->db->get('myTable')->result();
print_r($result);die();
```

Comment: some explanation is usually appreciated